# How to load a component from a variable name in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to load a component from a dynamic variable name in my vue.js application.

I have the following component registered:

```
<template id="goal">
  <h1>Goal:{{data.text}}</h1>
</template>
```

Instead of loading it like this

```
<goal></goal>
```

I want to load from a variable name, something like this:

```
<{{mytemplate.type}}></{{mytemplate.type}}>
```

Where, of course, mytemplate.type would be, in this case equal to "goal"

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use a [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) like this:

```html
<component :is="myTemplate.type"></component>
```

Answer (score 17):

I was having the same issue and because I was using Vue 3. After some research, I found out that the procedure to define dynamic components (async components) is a little different in Vue 3.
I hope this code helps someone.

```
<template>
    <component :is="comp"></component>
</template>

<script>
//Vue 3 is having a special function to define these async functions
import {defineAsyncComponent} from "vue";

export default {
 name: "DynamicComponent",
 //I am passing the name of the Component as a prop
 props: {
     componentName:{
         type: String,
         required: true
     }
 },
 computed: {
  comp () {
      return defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`../components/${this.componentName}.vue`))
  }
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Rakshit Arora above works, but only with './' and '../' in import.

As for now (2022), '@' symbol is not allowed in import (https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations).

Comment: This "answer" should be a comment.

Comment: His reputation isn't high enough to post comments yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have no reason to doubt the answer @Rakshit provided was valid, but for my case, I didn't need so much complexity. Figured I'd share if anyone was in the same boat--wanted to reference a different component for each v-tab in vuetify3, this code was sufficient:

```
  <v-toolbar color="info-light">
    <v-tabs v-model="tab">
      <v-tab v-for="item in items" :key="item" :value="item">
        {{ item.name }}
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  </v-toolbar>
  <v-window v-model="tab" fill-height>
    <v-window-item v-for="item in items" :key="item" :value="item">
      <component :is="item.component"></component>
    </v-window-item>
  </v-window>
```

And in the script section:

```
import ThatModule from "./ThatModule.vue";

export default {
  name: "CategorizeModule",

  data: () => ({
    tab: null,
    items: [
      {
        name: "Spending",
        component: <ThatModule></ThatModule>,
      },
```