# Dynamic Heroicons in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, heroicons

I assign the heroicon to a variable from my list of menu items.

```
const navigation = [{ name: 'Dashboard', icon: TemplateIcon, href: '#', current: true }]
```

Then I try to display the icon.

```
<li v-for="item in navigation" class="relative px-6 py-3">
    <TemplateIcon class="h-5 w-5" />
    <item.icon class="h-5 w-5" />
</li>
```

The template icon is only shown once, but should be shown twice.
I have already tried this

`<{{item.icon}} class="h-5 w-5" />`

`{{item.icon}}`

`<svg><path :d="item.icon"></path></svg>`

thx for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load a component from a variable name in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998790/how-to-load-a-component-from-a-variable-name-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) approach which is useful to dynamically switch between components.

This can be achieve by using Vue's `<component>` element with the special `:is` attribute.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    navigation: [{ icon: 'H3' }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in navigation" :key="index">
      <component :is="item.icon">Hello</component>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `component` component in vue.

You can find the documentation for it here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components

tldr, pass your component in the is prop

```html
<component :is="item.icon" class="h-5 w-5" />
```

Comment: Thank you! 
`<component :is="item.icon" class="h-5 w-5" />`
worked